# Problems with Outlook/Exchange on Xenapp

Tags: outlook, registry, citrix, xenapp

We have an Outlook pluggin that was working fine on Citrix (Xenapp) now it's behavior has deviated from what we see on a desktop. The question I have is the registry a shared resource in Xenapp or can we safely edit things like this Key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Options\Mail DWORD: EnableETWLogging Value: 1 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Options\Shutdown DWORD: FastShutdownBehavior Value: 2

Thanks
Tom

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely fine to edit the current user registry hive. That hive lives in the users' profile which is independent for every user.